# Prompting Until a Match is Found

Tags: python, validation, while-loop, user-input

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a volume of a cube

The validInput is either cube or c

```
validInput = ("cube" , "c")
```

This is the input that should be inputted if it wants to go through the next step

```
inputShape = input("Please tell me the shape you want to use (For example, Cube) ").lower()   

while inputShape != validInput:
inputShape = input("You've entered an invalid input. Please try again ")

if inputShape in cube:
    cubeValue = float (input ("Please input the value you want to use to calculate the volume of the cube"))
    def cubeVolume(cubeValue):
        cubeVolumeValue = cubeValue ** 3
        return cubeVolumeValue
    print("The volume of a pyramid with a length ", cubeValue, "is" , cubeVolumeValue)
```

The problem is, even If I enter cube or c, I get the invalid message, "You've entered an invalid input. Please try again ".

How do I make it so that I move on to the next step (which is inputting the float value)?

I'm stuck help  :(

Comment: Hi! Thanks for adding code. This looks like python, so I've added that tag.

Comment: You defined `validInput` to be a tuple of 2 strings, so it can _never_ equal `inputShape`, which is a single string. Also, you need to indent the line following the `while` line, correct indentation is vital in Python. And why have you defined the `cubeVolume` function inside that `if` block?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've messed up your conditional. Should be "while inputShape not in validInput".

Right now you're asserting that the inputShape is equal to the entire list of validInputs, which it isn't. You only need to check if the string exists somewhere in the list.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the "if inputShape in cube" condition is for. Don't even know if that will execute since cube isn't a defined variable. Did you want to check if it was a cube? Even in that case though, you already had the while loop check to see if it was a cube so you don't need to do another assertion.

Comment: so basically, trying to calculate the volume for cube, pyramid and ellipsoid.

Comment: is there a way i can reach u in private msg?

Comment: I see, so you're going to add more things to validInput. To check if the inputShape is a cube then, you should do something like this:

`if inputShape == "cube" or inputShape == "c"`

Comment: Idk, I don't think stackoverflow has message functionality, but just reply if you have any questions and I'll try to respond quickly

Comment: Oh thank you so much. 
Just trying to make it print the value now but I cant seem to print the value.

if inputShape == "cube" or inputShape == "c":
        cubeValue = float (input ("Please input the value you want to use to calculate the volume of the cube"))
        def cubeVolume(cubeValue):
            cubeVolumeValue = cubeValue ** 3
            return cubeVolumeValue
        print("The volume of a pyramid with a length ", cubeValue, "is" , cubeVolumeValue)

Comment: cant even seem to get the input msg out there which is:
input ("Please input the value you want to use to calculate the volume of the cube")

Comment: It's hard to read the code with the stackoverflow messages. Join this link and I can help you and we can chat on this as well

http://collabedit.com/r4tm8

Comment: sorry wasn't able to get back to you. I've updated the code on the website you've provided. Appreciate your kindness

Comment: updated the code

Comment: I added some suggested revisions, as well as offering a suggestion of where to go from there